# How to get records from one column such that there is no association with value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following MSSQL table:

```
Col1 Col2
A     x
A     y
A     z
B     x
B     y
C     x
C     z
```

I want all the values from Col1 such that they have no record of association with a particular value of Col2

For example, I want value from Col1 such that 'z' does not occur for that value. The answer should be B

Comment: Expected output

Comment: For example, I want all values from Col1 such that 'z' does not occur for that value. The answer should be B

Comment: Why not the answer `A` in the above condition ?

Comment: The 3rd row has A->z, similarly the last record has C->z, therefore I do not want C as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the lesser known `EXCEPT` keyword, like this :

```
SELECT Col1 FROM TableName
EXCEPT
SELECT Col1 FROM TableName WHERE col2 = 'z'
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/KPZMB79095

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 3):

One another way:

```
select Col1 
from your_table
group by Col1
having sum( case when Col2 = 'z' then 1 else 0 end ) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct col1 
     from [table] 
  where col1 not in (
                  select col1 from [table] where col2 = 'z'
                     );
```

Comment: while this could answer the question, provide some explanation about your answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. For me the clearest is to use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable
EXCEPT
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable WHERE Col2 = 'z';
```

Here we are clearly and simply saying that we want all the `Col1` values, except those `Col1` values that have a `z` entry. `EXCEPT` will automatically de-duplicate the result.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS** I think you want to retrieve the value where the given value does not exist in both the columns:

```
create table #sample(Col1 char(1), Col2 char(1))
insert into #sample values
('A',     'x'),
('A',     'y'),
('A',     'z'),
('B',     'x'),
('B',     'y'),
('C',     'x'),
('C',     'z')

declare @search char(1) = 'z'

select distinct col1 
from #sample
where col1 not in (
select distinct Col1
from #sample
where (col1 = @search or col2 = @search))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
col1
B
```